# Detecting cause of high in-bound network traffic

Tags: windows, networking, iis

One of our Windows/Coldfusion/IIS webservers has been experiencing a very odd pattern of high inbound network traffic.

[image]

In the picture above the red hum is out-bound traffic, and the yellow line is in-bound network traffic. It's very usual for a webserver which is sending out hundreds of requests per second of image and webpage data for the inbound traffic to be spiking that high. The IIS logs do not show users constantly uploading massive files either and generally our applications send out far more data than they receive.

I've attempted to use Microsoft Network Monitor but I really don't even know where to start with it. From the graph below it seems I should be able to detect some period spike of very large data transferring, but how do I detect that to find out exactly what it is the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The graph lines (in *Task manager* window, network tab) are showing you the inbound/outbound traffic **speed** (maximum bandwidth usage in %) but it doesn't gives you much information about the traffic **volume**.

I suggest that you look at the *Resource Monitor*: you will find that button in the *Performance*  tab of the *Windows Task Manager*.

Once in the *Resource monitor*, select the *Network* tab and from there you will be able to watch all the network activity in more details: including the processes involved, the I/O transfer speed and quantity, the active connections, etc...